# Do companions use up their enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on my PS3 and have thought of something none of my fellow skyrim playing friends can answer. If I were to give a companion an enchanted weapon, say a bow, would the enchantment ever run out?

Comment: @spartacus didn't come up when I posted the question, my bad.

Comment: no big deal, your question will become a pointer to the other one so its all good.